# how to loop over below statement

Tags: python, loops

```
sorted(X_train_num.F12.unique())==sorted(X_test_num.F12.unique())
```

basically I want to run loop over different variable like F12,F11,F78 etc. so that I can avoid writing the single command again and again for different variable.

Does someone knows simple way to loop over this statement with different var(F12,F11, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getattr`:

```
var = 'F12'
sorted(getattr(X_train_num, var).unique())==sorted(getattr(X_test_num, var).unique())
```

The above can be easily put in a loop.  For example:

```
for var in ('F10', 'F11', 'F12'):
    sorted(getattr(X_train_num, var).unique())==sorted(getattr(X_test_num, var).unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note: you can also do the comparison more efficiently by using *set* equality:

```
set(getattr(X_train_num, var)) == set(getattr(X_test_num, var))
```